# Por que no se disparan los eventos AuthenticationSuccessEvent y AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent luego de la autenticacion

Tags: java, jwt, spring-security

Estoy haciendo un tutorial donde se implementa un servicio luego de la autenticacion de Spring. El servicio se encarga de almacenar el usuario en cache y contar los intentos de login realizados. El problema es que el servicio nunca entra en accion ya que los eventos AuthenticationSuccessEvent o AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent no parecen ser "disparados".

el servicio...

```
@Service
public class LoginAttempService {
    public static final int ATTEMPS_MAX = 5;
    public static final int ATTEMPS_INCREMENT = 1;
    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> loginAttempCache;
    public LoginAttempService(){
        super();
        this.loginAttempCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).maximumSize(100)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
    }
    public void evictUserFromLoginAttempCache(String username){
        this.loginAttempCache.invalidate(username);
    }

    public void addUserToLoginAttempCache(String username) throws ExecutionException {
        int attempts = 0;
        attempts = ATTEMPS_INCREMENT + this.loginAttempCache.get(username);
        this.loginAttempCache.put(username, attempts);
    }

    public boolean hasExceededMaxAttemps(String username) throws ExecutionException {
        return loginAttempCache.get(username) >= ATTEMPS_MAX;
    }

}
```

esta es la configuracion la cual tiene sus anotaciones @Configuration y @EnablewebSecurity

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                     .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(SecurityConstant.PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll())
                     .csrf(config -> config.disable())
                     .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                     .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                     .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
                     .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);
                     return http.build();
    }
}
```

Listeners

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener{
    private LoginAttempService loginAttempService;
    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationSuccessListener(){
        this.loginAttempService = loginAttempService;
    }
    @EventListener
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event){
        Object principal = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if(principal instanceof User){
            User user = (User) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            this.loginAttempService.evictUserFromLoginAttempCache(user.getUsername());
        }
    }
}
```

Aca es donde quiero llegar debugueando pero nunca entra al breakpoint